# Restrict/change angle of body in Felgo

Tags: qt, qml, box2d, felgo

I have created a body in Felgo that, as a result of physical interaction with other objects, flips over.  I want to prevent the body from flipping over by limiting angle +/- 60' from horizontal.  Or, I would be happy to rotate the body (restore upright) in case it goes beyond that range.

How can I do that?  I tried the OnRotation of the body but that's getting me nowhere.

Comment: It looks like posts related to Felgo/V-Play have been in decline for years.  If someone can answer this question in relation to Box2D or QML-Box2d that would be great - I'm fine Dropping the Felgo requirement in this question if nececssary.  (Would have been nice to do in Felgo, but don't want to be restricted by a dying project)

Comment: could you provide any minimal working example that reflects your problem?